# authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I get an GoogleCredentials instance as below.

- GoogleCredentials Gcredentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("C:\Users\k...\service230314\steprate200901-9...00.json"))
  .createScoped(Lists.newArrayList("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform")); -
  The principal is active as below.
- gcloud auth list -
  Credentialed Accounts
  ACTIVE  ACCOUNT

- ```
    quehoraesxxxx@gmail.com
  ```

- - 

Then, Firestore instance as below.

- FirestoreOptions firestoreOptions_custom54 =FirestoreOptions.getDefaultInstance().toBuilder()
  .setProjectId("steprate220901")
  .setCredentials(Gcredentials)
  .build();
  Firestore db_custom54 = firestoreOptions_custom54.getService(); -
  This works properly when saving data. And firestoreOptions_custom54 has ServiceAccountCredentials@66 as below. But when downloading data, I can not to access using service accounts.
- gclud comment -
  c.g.a.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider  : Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead.
- firestoreOptions_custom54 -
  FirestoreOptions@118
  channelProvider:
  InstantiatingGrpcChannelProvider@121
  clientLibToken:
  "gccl"
  clock:
  CurrentMillisClock@123
  credentials:
  ServiceAccountCredentials@66
  credentialsProvider:
  AutoValue_FixedCredentialsProvider@124
  databaseId:
  "(default)"
  emulatorHost:
  null
  headerProvider:
  NoHeaderProvider@126
  host:
  "firestore.googleapis.com:443"
  projectId:
  "steprate220901"
  quotaProjectId:
  null
  retrySettings:
  AutoValue_RetrySettings@129
  rpc:
  null
  service:
  null
  serviceFactory:
  FirestoreOptions$DefaultFirestoreF -
  I expect to be able to access my data in firestore using my service accounts.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The problem is that though I'm using a service account to create the firestoreOptions instance, when I try to get the data using .getService() method, the error that I'm using the end user credentials instead of service account.

Comment: I was able to download data from Firestore normally with Eclipse and java8, but with VSCode and java17 using Service account, although it was the same code, I was able to upload data, but when I downloaded the data, permission was denied. By rewriting the code with reference to the following site, it became possible to download normally and it self-solved.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?hl=ja